# Excel VBA: Is there something simple causeing the error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Sub copyFilteredData2()

    Dim employee As String
    Dim AutoFiltrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FilterSh As Worksheet
    Dim DashSh As Worksheet
    Dim FilterRng As Range
    Set FilterSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
    Set DashSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Metrics Page")
Set FilterRng = FilterSh.Range("A1")
Dim Cell As Range


            FilterRng.AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:=DashSh.Range("E4").value

                    With FilterSh.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next

            Set AutoFiltrng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            If AutoFiltrng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data for that Engineer!"

            Else

            Worksheets(DashSh.Range("E4").value).Cells.Clear

            Set rng = FilterSh.AutoFilter.Range
            rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=DashSh.Range("E4").value

            End If

            End Sub
```

My goal with this code is to use a data set with data validation to filter information based on a value and then copy the information and paste it to a spread sheet that is named the same value. Ultimately I plan to build the code to loop through range E4:E25.

Comment: Usually when you hit debug, the highlighted line is where the error is

Comment: I get the common 1004 run time error. Copy method of range class failed...

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how I could clearly identify the range?

Comment: Remove the `.value` from `Destination:=DashSh.Range("E4").value`

Comment: We are on to something here. A.S.H. The destination goes onto the cell with the data point vs. the already created sheet with the same data point name.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can get the pivoting data point to interact with the filter copy and paste code?

Comment: I'm not getting it, but, is this what you want: `Destination:=Worksheets(DashSh.Range("E4").value).Range("A1")`   ?

Comment: That's the 1! Thank you for your help!!!